# Words read from file are null

Tags: java, file

I am attempting to read some words off of the file "words.txt", then use them in other classes of my program when it runs. This is what I have found on the internet, and it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
public static List<String> wordsList;


public static void refreshWords(){
    String fileName = "words.txt";

    String line = null;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            for(String tempWord : line.split(" ")){
                wordsList.add(tempWord);
            }
        }   

        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");
    }

}

public static List<String> getListOfWords(){
    return wordsList;
}
```

I, from the message displayed before the program even runs, which cancels the entire thing, can determine that the error is sparking from adding tempWord to wordsList. I would assume that tempWord is null, but I can't seem to find a reason why it is.

All that I have in the file are a bunch of random words that I thought of off the top of my head, formatted like the following:

this game turtle forest soccer football ball java list annoyed

Comment: "...the error is sparking from adding tempWord to wordsList. I would assume that tempWord is null, but I can't seem to find a reason why it is." - This rather indicates that the list itself is null as the Java Collections framework (usually) allows the items to be null.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Danstahr's solution has fixed it, I hadn't instanciated the list, only declared it. There was no real message, it just pointed to the line.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using there is the old way of doing it (before Java 7).
With Java 7 / 8, reading a file is much easier. So rather than looking for bugs, I'd rewrite this using the new API:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(yourFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

See [`Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Also, in your question, you are splitting lines into words. That's highly unusual, word lists are almost always one word per line.